# blockUI and flash content in IE

Tags: jquery, blockui

i am using blockUI to show content in modalbox. On my content page there is a flash video. In FF When the blockUI is active it overlaps everything including flash video, but in IE, flash video is overlapping the blockUI box. How to solve this issue in IE?

Comment: Block UI model popup is quite buggy with IE6. Which IE version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the object's `wmode` property to make it appear in front.

**[See this for more information.](http://www.askapache.com/css/getting-flash-to-show-up-in-front-of-content.html)**

Comment: @coure06: If you don't want that on top you may still need to specify the proper attribute so that it is not shown on top or you may also want to give the z-index css property to the element that you want to show on top.

Comment: Its only creating problem in IE